# What is recommended to Import Settings in Database project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I am importing already created database in visual studio 2013 from SQL server 2012. [image: Import database]

But I am little bit confused about why **import permissions** and **import database settings** is by default unchecked.

I think all the settings are important then why this so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason 1: Your database administrator may want to manage permissions and database-level settings directly on the server. (Also see Peter's comment)

Reason 2: Some people like to put database-level settings in a separate database project. This is useful when you have multiple databases on the same server, each having its own database project, and you don't want to duplicate the scripts for the logins & settings in each project. (That's how the pre-SSDT database projects worked. You'd create a *server* project for the server-level stuff in addition to your *database* projects.)

Comment: Slight tweak to Reason #1 - many people use different logins/users in each environment. Storing one set of users/logins/permissions won't necessarily be useful when pushing to other environments. Hoping MS eventually releases a solution for this so we don't have to use post-deploy scripts for permissions. This is one of the more painful areas to get set up initially for our projects.